# How to resolve 'getData()' method in recyclerview using android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, material-design, android-recyclerview

i have followed Slidenerd's tutorial on youtube on how to create a material design navigation drawer using android studio.
However on running the app i get this `cannot resolve method getData()` and on the console `Error:(56, 46) error: cannot find symbol method getData()` error on`adapter=new AdapterClass(getActivity().getData());`

There's probably somewhere i have overlooked.Any help will be appreciated.

NavigationDrawerFragment.java

```js
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;
    private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
    public static final String PREF_FILE_NAME = "testpref";
    public static final String KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "user_learned_drawer";
    private View containerView;
    private AdapterClass adapter;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    public NavigationDrawerFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mUserLearnedDrawer = Boolean.valueOf(readFromPreferences(getActivity(), KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, "false"));
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View layout=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
        recyclerView=(RecyclerView)layout.findViewById(R.id.drawerList);

       adapter=new AdapterClass(getActivity().getData());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        return layout;
    }

public static  List<Information> getData() {
    List<Information> data = new ArrayList<>();
    int[] icons = {R.drawable.ic_menu_check, R.drawable.ic_menu_check, R.drawable.ic_menu_check, R.drawable.ic_menu_check};
    String[] titles = {"Notifications", "School", "What's hot", "Hit us up"};

    for (int i=0;i<titles.length && i<icons.length;i++)
    {
        Information current=new Information();
        current.iconId=icons[i];
        current.title=titles[i];
        data.add(current);
    }
    return data;
}
    public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, Toolbar toolbar) {
        containerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                    mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                    saveToPreferences(getActivity(), KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, mUserLearnedDrawer + "");
                }
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }


            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();

            }

        };
        if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(containerView);
        }
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });
    }


    public static void saveToPreferences(Context context, String preferenceName, String preferenceValue) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(preferenceName, preferenceValue);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public static String readFromPreferences(Context context, String preferenceName, String defaultValue) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPreferences.getString(preferenceName, defaultValue);
    }
}
```

AdapterClasss.java

```js
public class AdapterClass extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterClass.MyViewHolder> {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
List<Information>data= Collections.emptyList();
    public AdapterClass(Context context,List<Information>data){
       inflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data=data;
    }
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
       View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row,parent,false);
        MyViewHolder holder=new MyViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Information current=data.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(current.title);
        holder.icon.setImageResource(current.iconId);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }
    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView title;
        ImageView icon;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.listText);
           icon=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.listIcon);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you perhaps place the specific code the error is talking about? Looks a bit cleaner, and makes it easier for others to follow.

Comment: what type of object is returned by  `getActivity()` ?? if class of  return type doesn't have `getData()` method then you will get this error.

Comment: @Bono and @Prashant the error comes from this code `adapter=new AdapterClass(getActivity().getData());` on the `onCreateView` method.`getData()` is supposed to return data from `List<Information>` array list as set by  `return data;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by doing it this way:

```
adapter = new AdapterClass(getActivity(), getData());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
adapter = new VivzAdapter(getActivity(),getData());
```

use this intead

```
adapter=new AdapterClass(getActivity().getData());
```

i had the same problem. ;-)